# Flutter build "Error connecting to the service protocol: failed to connect to http://127.0.0.1:1115/zE4MJXnfqIA=/" error on Android device

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter-test, flutter

I really tried to fix this issue. But I can't found another solution for this. I upgrade my flutter vision. [Flutter version: Channel stable, 2.2.1]. I upgrade my Android new vision [28/05/21].

I Used **Physical Device** to run my project

It's can't help me to fix that.

this is my error to get in:
**Launching lib\main.dart on SM J700F in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Error connecting to the service protocol: failed to connect to http://127.0.0.1:1115/zE4MJXnfqIA=/**

Flutter doctor:

Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):

**[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.985], locale en-US)**

**[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)**

**[X] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at .\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe)
! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.
[√] Android Studio**

**[√] Connected device (2 available)**

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.

Then I reset my Android physical Device but I can't find solution for this.

Comment: found a solution ?